# pyarrow autocomplete/intellisense in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyarrow

```
    import pyarrow as pa
    
    data = [
        pa.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
        pa.array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', None]),
        pa.array([True, None, False, True])
    
    ]
    
    batch : pa.RecordBatch = pa.record_batch(data, names=['f0', 'f1', 'f2'])
```

Above is the code I'm editing in vscode using the ms-python.python/ms-python.vscode-pylance extensions:

[image: vscode]

I'm not getting any autocomplete of methods/parameters etc., likely as most of pyarrow is implemented in native code. Are there any stubs, settings or other things I can do to get some nice autocomplete/intellisense with pyarrow in vscode ?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the language server type to **Jedi** through the following steps.

1. Use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>to open the *Settings* page
2. Search `python.languageServer`
3. Drop down to select `Jedi`

[image]

Or add the following configuration directly in the setting to complete the modification.

```json
    "python.languageServer": "Jedi",
```

[image]

Comment: Swapping to `Jedi` made no difference for me. [version info: `pyarrow==13.0.0` and Vscode Insiders 1.86.0]. It looks like there is only partial docstring coverage that is exposed. MyPy also complains about missing type stubs.